# Onos host event is not working

Tags: onos

I wrote an application in which I need to handle HOST_REMOVED events. I activated the Host Mobility application, but I receive

> 2017-06-07 21:59:13,565 | WARN  | tp1493291118-324 | UiWebSocket | 158 - org.onosproject.onos-gui - 1.11.0.SNAPSHOT | Unable to parse GUI message {"event":"requestDetails","payload":{"id":"FE:82:48:57:8C:48/None","class":"host"}} due to java.lang.NullPointerException

and my application doesn't catch the event whenever I administratively kill a host using REST API. I would be grateful if you can tell me what is wrong.

This is the source code:

```
private void recover(HostEvent hostEvent) {
    hostEvent.subject().ipAddresses().iterator().next().toInetAddress();
    ...
} 
private class InnerHostListener implements HostListener {
    @Override
    public void event(HostEvent event) {
        switch (event.type()) {
            case HOST_ADDED:
                break;
            case HOST_REMOVED:
                recover(event);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }//switch
    }
}
```

Comment: can you attach your source code ? you wrote an application that runs on top of onos or separated application that uses REST API of onos ?

Comment: My application is running on top of Onos.

Comment: is [this](https://github.com/opennetworkinglab/onos/blob/master/apps/mobility/src/main/java/org/onosproject/mobility/HostMobility.java) your host mobility application ?